# What's wrong with this Fibonacci code?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to write a Fibonacci sequence code where it takes a number as input and prints that many Fibonacci numbers.

```
def fibonacci(x):
    a = []
    a[0] = 0   
    a[1] = 1

    for i in range(2, x + 1):
        a[i] = a[i - 1] + a[i - 2]
        a += a[i]        

    return a
```

Comment: Use append to add to list. With your current implementation, you get an **out of range** error. Also the code inside your for loop is not syntactically correct.

Comment: How about this inside the for loop ?     a.append(a[i - 1] + a[i - 2]) return a

Answer (score 1):

`a = []` creates an empty array named a. `a[0]` cannot be instanced because it doesn't exist yet, it raises a out of range error

```
x = []
x[0] = 0 # <- error
```

What you need to append it like [append()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_append.htm)  or `a+=[]` :

```
def fibonacci(x):
    a = []
    a.append(0)   
    a.append(1)

    for i in range(2, x + 1):
        a.append(a[i - 1] + a[i - 2])
        #a +=[a[i - 1] + a[i - 2]]
    return a
```

Comment: Using the above code, I am getting this error 'None type has no attribute append'

Comment: Which line ? How do you compile/run it?

Comment: a.append(a[i - 1] + a[i - 2])

Comment: You cannot have this error because a is create just above.  Comment this line and uncomment the line bellow

Comment: Thanks, it worked. What was wrong with my code inside the for loop ?

Comment: As I explained, `a=[]` just declare an array, so `a[0]` doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah got it. Now "a.append(a[i-1] + a[i-2])" is also working..May be I did not save the file. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: No problem at all